# Issue with Auto-populate the location value on lookup field

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need the help on below visualforce and Apex code.

Am working in the requirement of "**Auto populate the location field whenever the custom lookup field Product_r.Level2__c contains 'Praise' or 'Expired'  means the another custom lookup field Locations__c needs to autopopulate/fill with the value of  ‘PRAISE – Location1’ in case record".**

Both the Product__c and Locations__c fields are lookup fields and Product__c field is relationship with Product__c object and this object contains the 3 levels (ProductLevel1__c, ProductLevel2__c, ProductLevel3__c).
And Locations__c field is relationship with Location_items__c object.

I tried to workout this requirement with below visual force and apex code. But it doesn’t work and not triggering with expected location value in location field. Also the below VFP and apex codes are not throwing any error also.

Any one please check and help me to complete this task.

VFP code:

```
<apex:inputField id=" Product_inputname" taborderhint="28" value="{!case. Product__c }" >
    <apex:actionSupport action="{!UpdateLocationField}" status="pageStatus" event="onchange"  reRender=" p2242" />
</apex:inputField>
<apex:inputField value="{!Case. Locations__c}" taborderhint="29 " id="p2242"  >
```

Apex method:

```
Public void UpdateLocationField() {
    String selectedProdId = cse.Product__c;

    if (selectedProdId!= null) {
        // Retrieve the Level2__c Product
        List<Product__c> selectedproduct = [SELECT Id, Level2__c FROM Product __c WHERE Id = :selectedProdId LIMIT 1];
        if (!selectedproduct.isEmpty()) {
            String level2Value = selectedproduct[0].Level2__c;
                
            // Set the Location field to ‘PRAISE – Location1' based on Level2__c value
            if (level2Value != null && (level2Value.contains('Expired') || level2Value.contains('Praise')) ){
                // Query for the PRAISE – Location1' value from Location_items__c object
                List< Location_items__c > praiseLocations = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Location_items__c WHERE Name = 'PRAISE – Location1' LIMIT 1];
                    
                if(!praiseLocation.isEmpty()) {
                    Locations_ items__c praiseLocationvar = praiseLocations[0];
                        
                    // Update the Case record's Locations__c field with PRAISE – Location1' value
                    this.cse. Locations__c = praiseLocationvar.Id;
                        
                    // Update the Case record
                    update cse;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any response from anyone please??